# How to Calculate Outer wall length from wall angles

Tags: javascript, math, trigonometry, angle

I'm coding a small project with a friend and we're currently trying to create a wall building system so the users can place their own walls Similar to the Building system found in The Sims but the problem we face is that we cannot seem to get the outer Walls to join to make a perfect corner

We can detect when two walls make a corner and can also detect the Orientation, Length and Width of each wall, but just cannot find the outside size the walls need to grow so they create a perfect corner

Any help is much Appreciated

Comment: This is more of a math problem. Anyway, the answer is `thickness / tan(angle/2)`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is the kind of question that is practically impossible to answer without a diagram. And I assume you also know the *locations* of the walls.

Comment: Thanks for your Replies, Chris G was right, I guess he's faced a similar problem before, Life saver!